# problem installing ros full ubuntu 10.4

Tags: rosinstall

[image: Rosanswers logo]

the comand line end the error are

```
sudo apt-get install ros-diamondback-desktop-full
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ros-diamondback-desktop-full : Depends: ros-diamondback-ros-tutorials (= 0.2.4-s1312445230~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
                                Depends: ros-diamondback-geometry-tutorials (= 0.1.3-s1312445373~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
                                Depends: ros-diamondback-slam-gmapping (= 1.2.3-s1312435634~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
                                Depends: ros-diamondback-ros (= 1.4.9-s1312417708~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
                                Depends: ros-diamondback-visualization (= 1.4.1-s1312432000~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
                                Depends: ros-diamondback-vision-opencv (= 1.4.3-s1312425872~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
                                Depends: ros-diamondback-perception-pcl (= 0.10.0-s1312427042~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
                                Depends: ros-diamondback-rx (= 1.4.2-s1312430459~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
                                Depends: ros-diamondback-image-pipeline (= 1.4.2-s1312437407~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
                                Depends: ros-diamondback-simulator-gazebo (= 1.2.8-s1312440157~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
                                Depends: ros-diamondback-diagnostics-monitors (= 1.4.0-s1312439740~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
                                Depends: ros-diamondback-simulator-stage (= 1.2.5-s1312437801~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
                                Depends: ros-diamondback-image-common (= 1.4.1-s1312425748~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
                                Depends: ros-diamondback-common-tutorials (= 0.1.2-s1312463072~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
                                Depends: ros-diamondback-ros-comm (= 1.4.7-s1312424712~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
                                Depends: ros-diamondback-visualization-common (= 1.4.2-s1312430681~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
                                Depends: ros-diamondback-physics-ode (= 1.4.1-s1312430103~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
                                Depends: ros-diamondback-driver-common (= 1.2.3-s1312425659~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
                                Depends: ros-diamondback-executive-smach (= 1.0.2-s1312435548~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
                                Depends: ros-diamondback-common-msgs (= 1.4.0-s1312425065~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
                                Depends: ros-diamondback-image-transport-plugins (= 1.4.1-s1312426755~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
                                Depends: ros-diamondback-robot-model (= 1.4.0-s1312427974~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
                                Depends: ros-diamondback-visualization-tutorials (= 0.2.2-s1312464635~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
                                Depends: ros-diamondback-geometry (= 1.4.2-s1312425346~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
                                Depends: ros-diamondback-documentation (= 1.4.1-s1312464754~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
                                Depends: ros-diamondback-executive-smach-visualization (= 1.0.1-s1312459854~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
                                Depends: ros-diamondback-laser-pipeline (= 1.2.0-s1312429600~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
                                Depends: ros-diamondback-common (= 1.4.3-s1312425161~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
                                Depends: ros-diamondback-diagnostics (= 1.4.0-s1312425553~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
                                Depends: ros-diamondback-navigation (= 1.4.1-s1312429823~lucid) but it is not going to be installed"
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10911/problem-installing-ros-full-ubuntu-10.4/) by [natan](https://answers.ros.org/users/960/natan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2011-08-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You have a problem in your package sources/package install. Can you update your original post with your /etc/apt/sources.list? There should only be lucid entries in there.

Some package is "blocking" your install. To figure out the cause, you can choose one in the list, where it says "but is not going to be installed", and install only that. If you get a similar error there, continue with the package causing the next error until you get a different error.

Usually you arrive at some error that tells you it wants a package in a certain version, but it can only be installed in another one (or not at all). Post that error here.

In general you should make sure that your /etc/apt/sources.list only contains lucid entries, run `apt-get update` and then resolve the situation.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-08-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2